# Datetime unix to ISO Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, data-analysis

Hello I have this dataframe:

```
    TimeStamp       low      high      open     close      volume
0   1514331900  15699.54  15800.00  15699.55  15790.88   62.675508
1   1514331000  15651.57  15745.80  15662.01  15699.54   83.040542
2   1514330100  15661.00  15820.01  15820.01  15662.00   67.716571
3   1514329200  15780.00  15856.00  15780.01  15820.00   41.608696
4   1514328300  15780.00  15867.01  15789.98  15780.00   50.103055
5   1514327400  15719.00  15856.99  15856.99  15789.99  120.660673
```

I set timestamp as index

```
df.set_index('TimeStamp')
```

I get

```
                  low      high      open     close      volume
TimeStamp                                                     
1514331900  15699.54  15800.00  15699.55  15790.88   62.675508
1514331000  15651.57  15745.80  15662.01  15699.54   83.040542
1514330100  15661.00  15820.01  15820.01  15662.00   67.716571
1514329200  15780.00  15856.00  15780.01  15820.00   41.608696
1514328300  15780.00  15867.01  15789.98  15780.00   50.103055
```

Now I want to convert the timestamp to ISO human readable DateTime.
So I use pandas library

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='s')
```

But I don't get the expected datetime, I get this:

```
                      TimeStamp       low      high      open     close  \
1970-01-01 00:00:00  1514331900  15699.54  15800.00  15699.55  15790.88   
1970-01-01 00:00:01  1514331000  15651.57  15745.80  15662.01  15699.54   
1970-01-01 00:00:02  1514330100  15661.00  15820.01  15820.01  15662.00   
1970-01-01 00:00:03  1514329200  15780.00  15856.00  15780.01  15820.00   
1970-01-01 00:00:04  1514328300  15780.00  15867.01  15789.98  15780.00
```

It's not the correct form because If I do:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1514331900, unit='s')
Timestamp('2017-12-26 23:45:00')
```

I get the accurate date.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was not able to duplicate your problem.  What version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.21.1
It works fine for you?

Comment: This is an `inplace` versus `copy` issue. You need to assign `df.set_index('TimeStamp')` to `df`. Basically, `df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')` or  use `inplace`: `df.set_index('TimeStamp', inplace=True)`. Otherwise you're converting `range(len(df))` to datetime objects.

Comment: Oh yea... your second statement set_index must be reassigned as Abdou.  `df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')`.

Comment: It's working now! 
Just use this!
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')

df.set just returns a len.. 

Thanks guys!

Comment: If you have it working, consider answering your own question and accepting that answer, so the question doesn't stay open.

Comment: you are wright, I did it already!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The function

```
df.set_index('TimeStamp')
```

to actually change the dataframe  it needs to be done like:

```
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')
```

or

```
df.set_index('TimeStamp', inplace=True)
```

otherwise we are just converting a len